# Nullable Bit field true or false detection

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities, nullable

If I have a nullable bit field (named 'Disabled') and the data is as follows:

```
ID | Name | Disabled
--------------------
1  | Mine | null
2  | Yours| 1
```

If I then execute the following Linq To Entities statement no values are returned:

```
from r in Rates
where r.Disabled != true
select r
```

But If I execute this Linq To Entities statement:

```
from r in Rates
where r.Disabled == true
select r
```

It returns the expected one row with an ID of 2.

I want the first statement to return row 1 where the value of the 'Disabled' field is null.

Am I missing a trick here? Why does the first statement not return the null valued row?

**Edit** let me rephrase the question... Why isn't it returning the null rows? I know I can put in a simple null check.

Comment: `NULL != true` return false

Comment: try replacing `where r.Disabled != true` with `where (r.Disabled ?? false) != true` This will replace any null found with false for this comparison

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That's most illogical... NULL != true returning false is implying that NULL == true ?!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @PaulZahra Is a design thing. `NULL != false`  is also false. You can read this [**why-null-never-compares-false**](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/) That is why they create the `IS` operator for `fieldName IS NULL`

Comment: @PaulZahra `null` is not true or false. `null` has no value, and by definition will never be equal to anything except other `null`s.

Comment: SQL uses three valued logic - `true`, `false`, `unknown` - `NULL != true` is `unknown`. negating `unknown` returns `unknown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from r in Rates
where r.Disabled != true
   || r.Disabled IS NULL
select r
```

Comment: That is invalid code for Linq To Entities... it should read r.Disabled != true || r.Disabled == null

Comment: Taking into account the information you presented me with I will mark this as the answer... thanks!

Comment: By the way... I decided to go with the slightly more logical ... r.Disabled == false || r.Disabled == null

Comment: Yes I was still in SQL mode. Yes second version is more readeable

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have nullable bool. You can check for null by `HasValue`.

```
bool? nullableBool = null;
if (nullableBool.HasValue == false)
    {
      //Null
    }
```

If you want to treat `false` and `null` as same as "NOT TRUE", then you can use `GetValueOrDefault` propertry

```
bool? nullableBool = false;
```

or `bool? nullableBool = false;`

In either of the two cases, this `if` condition will meet.

```
if (!nullableBool.GetValueOrDefault(false))
    {

    }
```

You can use these logic in your code.

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it in the query... and if I do i get this error 'NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean GetValueOrDefault(Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: what about HasValue?